# My NUnit Test Adapter extension to Visual Studio 2015 is disabled regularly despite me not doing anything

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit, visual-studio-extensions

I have the NUnit 3 Test Adapter installed for Visual Studio 2015.  It regularly is disabled, despite the fact I do not disable it.  Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for your reference.

> 1.Uninstall the extension
>
> 2.Restart VS
>
> 3.Uninstall the extension (it was still there!)
>
> 4.Restart VS
>
> 5.Install the extension

For more information, please refer to:

https://github.com/nunit/docs/issues/141

Comment: I had to repeat the operation 3 times, but in the end it works fine for me too !